# Alternative method for deprecated Encode.forUri() method

Tags: java, security, uri, encode, urlencode

I want to replace Encode::forUri with something that is not depricated. Does anyone know what method should I use to cover that up? I can't use forUriComponent() because I have to convert an link, not a query, and also forUriComponent() doesn't convert all the characters as forUri() did

Code example:

```
private static final ImmutableList<UnaryOperator> ENCODING_CHAIN_URL_IN_HTML_ATTRIBUTE = ImmutableList.of(Encode::forUri, EsEncode::uriAsSafeSchemeUri, Encode::forHtml);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use

```
URLEncoder.encode("NAME", "UTF-8");
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Example

```
URLEncoder.encode(
    "urlStringParams",
    java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()
  )
```

Comment: If you're using Java 10 or up, you can omit the `toString()`: `URLEncoder.encode("urlStringParams', StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`. That way you don't have to catch that annoying checked exception.